# Do distros not compile the kernel, and if so how?

Tags: linux, kernel

Heyo! I'm a regular Gentoo user, who manually builds everything. Hence, this is a stupid question, but a question nonetheless - do distros like Ubuntu *not* compile the kernel while installing? Like, could I just compile the kernel once, and just cp the lib files over to a new setup? I.e., is there a way to have pre-compiled binaries for the kernel, and do other distros use it?

Thanks, and cheers!

Answer (score 2):

> do distros like Ubuntu not compile the kernel while installing?

They are binary distros, you download and install already compiled packages.

> Like, could I just compile the kernel once, and just cp the lib files over to a new setup?

You can use a self-compiled Linux kernel in any Linux distro. I'm on Fedora and I don't even have a distro kernel installed - I compile it by myself.

> I.e., is there a way to have pre-compiled binaries for the kernel, and do other distros use it?

You mean your pre-compiled binaries? You're free to package your kernel as a deb file in Debian/Ubuntu and their derivatives. The same applies to Fedora/RHEL/Suse - only you package it as an RPM.

If you want to install your kernel on many PCs you'll have to create a repository which is distro dependent.

Comment: I meant your very last point - I know you can compile your own kernel on any distro, but can I compile it on this PC and then install my distro on another PC with that same kernel? (considering arch, etc. are the same). Say I don't have access to .deb and .rpm files - how would I package it then?

Comment: Each distro has its own way of rebuilding the installer image, so you'll have to Google it. Of course, you'll first need to compile your own kernel and e.g. for Ubuntu still package it as a deb package. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization

Comment: And if I'm using a distro from scratch? Could I just copy the /boot/vmlinu* files from an existing setup of that distro to a new installation of that distro? Reason being, I don't want the installer for that distro to compile the kernel from the bottom up if possible, to spare time.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu provides precompiled modular kernels in its repositories but, as with any distribution, any operator of a host is also welcome to install the kernel source (also available in its repositories) and compile a kernel by hand if desired.

Comment: I understand that anyone can compile their own kernel to their distro - what interests me is pre-compiling a kernel. What files do I need to provide for a pre-compiled modular kernel?